# Send images in Email inside the body in Python

Tags: python, django, email

How do I send images in body of the e-mail in Python. I googled it, but was able to find the attachment method. How do I send it inline?

Here's my code:-

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

    subject = 'Report for ' + filename
    content = 'Hello All \nPFA  ' + filename + '. \n\n\nThis is an auto generated mail. Please do not reply to this email. '
    receipients =['x','y']
    sender = ''

    message = EmailMessage(subject,content,sender,bcc = receipients)
    message.attach_file(filepath)
    message.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this by directly setting a text content. The easiest way is probably to send a mail with html using django template rendering system. That way you can directly include the image the way you want (for instance `<img src="...">`)

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string   

mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject, 
    render_to_string('template.txt',
    sender,
    recipients
)
mail.attach_alternative(render_to_string('template.html', {'image_src': '...'}), 'text/html'))
mail.send()
```

Note that it's considered good practice to include a plain text mail also (without the image) in case the receiver mail system cannot read html (almost never happens). To be more clear, `template.html` and `template.txt` are the same content that you want to send, but with or without any html. For instance

### `template.txt`

```
Hello All \nPFA  \n\n\nThis is an auto generated mail. Please do not reply to this email.
```

### `template.html`

```
<p> Hello All </p>PFA  </br> <img src=" {{ image_src }} "> ...
```

Comment: What is template.txt?

Comment: Is template.html a file kept on a server?

Comment: Yes. I assumed that you were familiar with the django templating system. If not, you can start [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/) or [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

Comment: No. I'm. But according to my requirement, I need to send a mail every hour, so to make a new template file for each image source, is out of question. Is there any other method

Comment: What do you mean? You don't have to create a file each time you send a file, the file is not removed, it just stays in your django project with your code. No the only way to directly include an image without an attachment is through html.

Comment: Yes I agree the file is not removed but the image name is changed after every hour, hence I'm guessing that I need to change the img name inside the template.html file, thereby making new html files ever now and then. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's why contexts are made for, you can simply pass the image source to the template (see updated answer).

Comment: Thanks, Let me try and I'll get back to you. Thanks a lot

Comment: The image does comes in the bpdy, but does not appear in it.  Any reasons why? I've tested the template.html page while opening it in the browser and it appears there but not in the mail. ?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast how did you fixed this issue. 
I'm adding an image link which is in a S3 bucket. It is showing properly on browser, but nothing in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `base64` and embedding data inline in email body, for example:

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```

gives: http://jsfiddle.net/rinz/jDjb5/

Comment: Encoded image to use it inline, (using base64 encoding)